# Our vendor created the IPFS and Ethereum platform to store the PDF documents. How do i use the same code in Desktop Application

Tags: dapps, ipfs

I am a quiet layman in IPFS and Ethereum. Our vendor created the web application which stores the documents IN IPFS (Ethereum). Now, we do need to do the same in the desktop application also. Unfortunately, our vendor is no longer supporting on this.

Kindly help, what we should refer in the web application and how to build the same logic in the desktop application in order to follow the solution as written in the web application for IPFS / Ethereum decentralized documents management.

Comment: Are you sure you want to go for a Desktop Application? Most applications nowadays are Web Applications, especially for a DApp where you anyway need to connect to a remote network (be it IPFS or Blockchain). How would your desired Desktop Application be different from a Web one?

Comment: This is more of a business problem and not narrowly scoped out technical problem that would be answerable. Simple answer would be "hire a developer who understands and supports the earlier work of vendor and can integrate it to a technical application".